# Excel 2013 Help Offline View

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there a way to enable offline viewing of Excel 2013's help window like that of 2010's?

Every time I hit the <kbd>F1</kbd> key, Excel wants to connect to the internet to help me!

**Edit:** Is there a way to enable offline viewing for VBA for Excel 2013 as well?

Answer (score 4):

Open Help in Excel. At the top of the Help window click the little arrow to the right of the **Excel Help** title. In the drop-down menu select **Excel Help from your computer**:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! But I wanted Offline help for VBA too!

Answer (score 1):

You can download offline VBA help here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40326

Comment: Unfortunately, the downloaded offline help isn't integrated into VBA. If you hit F1 on a keyword in VBA, it still goes to Internet.